# Designing administration interface with GWT

Tags: gwt, user-interface

I need to develop simple administration interface. Something with a menu on the side and main window. I think about using `GWT` to build it.

The admin app needs to use RPC to communicate with server side and get the system's status etc.

I prefer not starting the design from scratch and build on well known generic UIs. I was wondering if there are any GWT project templates/ examples for doing such a job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some UI Frameworks:

- GXT : http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/
- Smart GWT : http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/

Comment: We use Smart GWT and I have to say there is just one issue - pretty huge API. Everything what you can image is already implemented there, just should know what a method to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

It true there are a lot of functionality in GXT UI framework.But to build a beautiful UI for administrator I will suggest GWT-Bootstrap which has very awesome components.

Refer following tutorial : 
[gwtbootstrap3 demo](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#home)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap would be a good choice though I ultimately decided it was an overkill for what I wanted to do. Mobile-friendly simplicity is key. I can live w/o 5 kinds of "dropdown buttons".

Invest in styling instead of jumping to third-party libraries like SmartGWT. I've wasted four years on before finally being fed up. It severely handicaps GWT, not to mention performance and bugs.

It took me one day to style my UI to produce a fluid mobile-friendly look and feel. GWT has everything built-in to do that, but it doesn't offer any prebuilt styles, and the standard colors and gradients found on it's Showcase page look a little crude.